# "INVALID_TYPE_ON_FIELD_IN_RECORD" while updating date/dateTime field using SOAP client

Tags: datetime, date, soap, field-update, wsc

I have a SOAP client which connects with Salesforce and do CRUD operations.
Earlier I used to use Axis to generate stub and in that case it works perfectly but then I replaced axis with force-wsc due to some security vulnerabilities with axis.
Here when I'm trying to update a date/datetime field it shows "INVALID_TYPE_ON_FIELD_IN_RECORD". Below are the two soap envelope created by axis(1st) and force-wsc(2nd) . Please let me know how can I resolve this issue.

[image: axis generated soap envelope]

[image: wsc generated soap envelope]

Comment: Try to remove 'T' from the datetime, like: ```2019-06-19 07:00:45```

Comment: And erase your session token from the screenshots or at least kill current session, because it's security vulnerability.

Comment: Sure @MariiaIllarionova . I will kill the current session . Removing 'T' is not a option for us as we have developed a large solution where it is being used like this and changing it requires a lot of effort . I will try to use it by removing it to see if that works at least.

Comment: The explicit `xsi:type="xsd:string"`on EmailBouncedDate seems the likely cause of the problem. Try sending the same SOAP request with something like SOAPUI, but exclude that attribute.

Comment: Yup, it is working that way . But now the question is , how can we specify this to force-wsc while it generates the envelope ?